# Returning the longest set in a dictionary of sets?

Tags: python, dictionary, set, anagram

I'm working on an anagram program wherein a text file of words and a given length are passed as command arguments.  Only anagrams of the given length should be considered.  The program is supposed to print only the words in the largest set.  If there's several equally large sets, all should be printed. I'm fairly confused.
example:
ares 
arse
ears
eras
rase
sear
sera

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
def main():
try:
    if len(sys.argv) > 2:
        filename = sys.argv[1]
        global length
        length = int(sys.argv[2])
        wordDict = readFile(filename)
        print(wordDict)
except IOError:
    print("Error: file not found.")
except NameError:
    print("Error: a text file and a length are required.")


def readFile(filename):
    inFile = open(filename, "r")
    try:
        return readData(inFile)
    finally:
        inFile.close()

def readData(inFile):
    wd = defaultdict(set)
    for line in inFile:
        line = line.strip()
        if length == len(line):
            wd["".join(sorted(line))].add(line)
    j = [k for k, v in wd.items() if len(v)==mx]
    return j
main()
```

Comment: Where does your random `length` come from in `readData`?

Comment: Length comes from the command line argument for length up in def main().  I declared it global, I know there's a better way to do this.

Comment: If your problem is resolved, then accept the answer. Otherwise, what is not working?

Comment: I added an edit, I do need other equally large sets.  I'm having trouble with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, how do you get the biggest anything in some iterable? The `max` function with a `key` argument that specifies how you measure the values.

How do you measure the length of a set? The `len` function.

How do you get an iterable of all of the values in a dict? The `values` method (or, in 2.x, `itervalues`).

So:

```
max(d.values(), key=len)
```

For example:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'a'},
...      'art': {'art', 'rat', 'tar'},
...      'at': {'at', 'ta'}}
>>> max(d.values(), key=len)
{'art', 'rat', 'tar'}
```

Of course if there are two equally-large sets, you're going to get one arbitrarily. But since you're just asking for "the largest", that seems like a reasonable interpretation.

---

If you want all of the equally-largest sets, there are a few ways you could do that.

One obvious possibility is to do it explicitly. Consider how you'd implement `max`: just check each value, and if it's greater than the biggest value you've seen so far, it's the new biggest value. (This is only marginally complicated by the `key` function; it just means you have to compare `key(value) > key(biggest_value)`.) Now, how would you implement an `all_max` function? Just keep a list or set of equally-big biggest values. If each new value is greater than any of the biggest values, you have a new list with just the one new value; if it's equal, add it to the existing list.

But if you think about it, you can just use the same multi-dict trick again: create a dict mapping lengths to sets of that length. (You do need one minor trick here: sets aren't hashable, but frozensets are.) Then you just pick the biggest length. Of course if you don't need the dict for anything beyond the first lookup, it's a waste of memory to store it, but often these kinds of things are useful repeatedly.

```
>>> length_d = defaultdict(set)
>>> for value in d.values():
...     length_d[len(value)].add(frozenset(value))
>>> max(length_d)
3
>>> length_d[max(length_d)]
{frozenset(['rat', 'art', 'tar'])}
```

OK, not particularly exciting in my example, since there's only one length-3 set, but you get the idea.

If you want something more concise, at the cost of a bit of performance (it'll be log-linear time instead of linear), you can always just sort by size (`sorted(d.values(), key=len, reverse=True)`), then iterate until you get a smaller value (e.g., with `itertools.takewhile`).

Comment: I need equally large sets as well.  If say, I do largest = sorted(max(wd.values(), key=len)) , I believe I have to compare against it and test whether any further sets(the values) are equal?  I'm rather confused.